# What Parameter set is correct for translating Java files to pascal units with Java2OP

Tags: delphi, javadoc

My goal is to translate a Java Project (3 `.java` files) to `.pas` files with Embarcadero's [Java2OP tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android).

I'm using it via `cmd`, started in the `java2op` directory.  After several unsuccessful tries, and a lot of time of googling, I am frustrated.

Commands in the documentation:

```
Input Options
-------------
-classes Space-separated list of names of classes or packages to export. -classes lets 
         you define a specific subset of the specified Java sources (-jar or -source options) 
         or the Android API.
-jar     Space-separated list of input Java compiled libraries (.jar files).
-source  Space-separated list of input folders containing Java source files (.java files).

Output Options
--------------
-unit    File name of the output unit.
         Default: Android.JNI.Interfaces

Examples
--------
Exporting some classes and packages from the Android API:

  Java2OP.exe -classes android.net.ConnectivityManager android.location.*

Exporting all classes from mylib.jar:

  Java2OP.exe -jar mylib.jar

Exporting a single class from mylib.jar:

  Java2OP.exe -jar mylib.jar -classes com.mypackage.ClassName

Exporting all the classes from a folder of Java sources specifying the
file name of the  output Delphi unit:

  Java2OP.exe -source myproject/src -unit Android.JNI.UnitName
```

My commands:

```
java2op.exe -src A:\Tests -unit Android.JNI.TestFile
```

So it matches the guidelines:

```
Java2OP.exe -source myproject/src -unit Android.JNI.UnitName
```

If I try to change `-src` to the suggested `-source`, I get the following error:

> Invalid option: -source

After executing the command, 1 error occurs:

> Command: javadoc -J-Xmx1024m -encoding "UTF-8"  -sourcepath "A:\java2op\Java"
>   -subpackages "" -classpath "" -bootclasspath "A:\java2op\bootclasses.jar" -docletpath "A:\java2op\doclava.jar"
>   -doclet com.google.doclava.Doclava -nodocs -public -apixml "A:\java2op\temp.xml"
>
> Output: javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "" 1 error

I read the following post about the same issue:

[How can I extract a Delphi class from this JAVA file for use with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039052/how-can-i-extract-a-delphi-class-from-this-java-file-for-use-with-android)

but without success.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Open a command prompt and go to the folder containing Java2op.exe for your Delphi version (in Berlin, it's in {$BDSDIR}\Bin\converters\java2op) and type Java2op and hit enter. The proper parameters are listed in the output; look for *options:* in the text.

Comment: I just add the path to Java2OP in my PATH variable

Comment: @KenWhite, I did both. Problem still exists. There are two warnings, error opening ReserverdWordsOP.txt and error opening ReservedWordsC.txt then pasing the bootclasses xlm passes. It then continues with parsing the source, then an error occurs with processing the source folder. Then there is an information "See doclava.log for more info" but in the java2op folder is no log file i searched with a tool called everything but still nothing...